# Android: Increase Geofences accuracy

Tags: android, android-studio, geolocation, geofencing, indoor-positioning-system

I'm building an app using Geofences, right now the minimum radius I can set so my geofence can get accurately detected is 30m. I want to be able to set a minimum radius of 5m.

In the [Android Developers documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing) about geofences says:

> When indoor location is available, the accuracy range can be as small as 5 meters.

What does it mean with the indoor location? Is it something I should enable in the phone? I don't get it. Also I looked over internet and I know that the accuracy of a geofence is perform by the system and cannot get the Wifi RTT or anything else work with it.

What can anyone do to get a better accuracy for geofences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indoor location means using bluetooth beacons to determine a more exact location via triangulation.  It only works in a predefined area as you need special hardware in the physical location.  Getting it down to 5m outside would require GPS hardware more powerful than in the typical phone.  The typical phone is accurate to only about 10m in the best case.  What you wan't just isn't possible.